# web form open in new tab dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page. And a tab container is on the Master page. This master page have a menu. Now I want that Click on the Menu item, the WebForm/UserControl open in the tab panel in the tab container dynamically with closing button. Please help me.

Comment: would you please bother posting some markup

Comment: I have not code for this. I want to just start the above work. But i don't know how could i start for the above work

Answer (score 0):

The page will post-back normally , but if you use Ajax then it will look like clicking on the master page link loaded the tab content dynamically.
Can help more if you can post your code.

If you like to have a popup panel with close button (didn't understand your question properly) use model popup extender.

Comment: I want to open WebForm/usercontrol only in new tab dynamically with close button not open in model popup extender.

Comment: Tab withing your page right ? If not code then please provide the design layout to explain it further.

Comment: Actually i am a new user. So i am not able to upload image.                   If you don't mind would you give me your email id to send image

Comment: upload on www.tinypic.com and post the image link here, so others can also see and help.

Comment: Sir, I upload the image to the above given link

Comment: From your image I can see that you are talking about browser tab, not a tab within your application. For the url's you are going to put in your menu links you simply need to do something like this :

`<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              NavigateUrl="your new page url"
              Text="New"
              Target="_blank"
              runat="server"/>`

The **Target = "_blank"** property will open the link in the menu item in a new tab.

More info about the target property here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx